# Android/XML - How to align/scale different images together?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

Basically I have one image, that has various layers. I've separated those layers out into separate images, so I can manipulate them programmatically. An example would be an image of a face, where each part(eyes, nose, mouth) I've separated into their own images. The issue comes in when I'm trying to align them all as they were in the original image, in the same places. They don't scale the same, and I need them aligned precisely where they were in the original image. Is there a way to set them up in XML so that they match the scale and stay that way while remaining separate images? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, I just can't seem to figure it out. If there is a better option than what I'm attempting, that is fine too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that all of your images have the same size, that's the most reasonable approach. Now wrap them all in one FrameLayout, set all images with, height to match parent and control the width/height of the FrameLayout. All of the ImageViews will keep the same proportions